# Does ActiveMQ provide kerberos (GSSAPI) authentication over TCP/AMQP/STOMP connectors

Tags: activemq-classic, kerberos

Can anyone tell me if (or when) ActiveMQ provides a kerberos (GSSAPI) based authentication scheme? Google tells me that someone added a naive kerberos plugin for HTTPS connector, but I'm interested in a more versatile solution which will provide support for single-sign on authentication along with wrapped/encrypted messages for all the connectors.

Does anyone know of any other message brokers which provide the same functionality ?

Thanks & Regards,
Bhanu

Comment: Did you solve your question? We have the same problem right now!

Comment: Nopes ! Planning to do something by myself. Did you find anything in this regard ?

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis can do this. Check out [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#kerberos-authentication).